# NSMutableArray have restriction in adding object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am using `NSMutableArray` for adding objects.But its add only first 10 objects.
I have code for sharing

```
  for (int j = 0; j<[feedData count]; j++)
    {

       [sharingItems addObject:[self whatsappdata:[feedData objectAtIndex:j]]];

    }
```

This method return `NSString` type text.

Please provide me valid solution for this.

Thanks in Advance

```
      -(NSString *)whatsappdata:(NSDictionary *)cellData1
      {

NSString *brandName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cellData1 objectForKey:@"brand_name"]];
NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cellData1 objectForKey:@"brand_model_name"]];

NSString *version = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cellData1 objectForKey:@"version_name"]];
if ([version  isEqualToString: @"<null>"])
{
    version = @"";
}
NSString *year = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [cellData1 objectForKey:@"model_year"]];
if (year == nil || [year isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    year = @"";
}
NSString *inventoryValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellData1 objectForKey:@"inventory_type"]];
NSInteger value = [inventoryValue intValue];
NSString *inventoryName;
NSString *msg;
if(value == 1)
{
    inventoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Stock"];
    i++;
    NSString *text2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.%@ %@ %@- %@ Single Owner\n",i, brandName, modelName, version, year];
    msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text2];
    msg= [msg  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"<br/>"];
}
else
{
    inventoryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Required"];
    msg = @"";
}



return msg;
//end data

   }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for initializing the Array?

Comment: sharingItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Comment: whats count of feedData?

Comment: its nsmutable array which hold data from server(json)

Comment: is WhatsAppData a function. Does it return anything.

Comment: yes its return nsstring

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: Try to simply add a NSString to sharingItems to rule out some weird shit inside the whatsappdata: method. What's the count of feedData? Are you using sharingItems anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code. As Piyush already asked, how many items are actually in `feedData`? That is, what's the value of `[feedData count]`? The issue must be that you only put 10 items into the array as there is no limit in `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Indeed; `NSLog(@"%ld", feedData.count);` should immediately answer your direct question: no. NSArray does not drop items after the tenth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably "***fetch limit***" has set for '***NSFetchRequest***' inside your code.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];//such code you need to find and remove/change fetch limit
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate memory to array before adding elements

```
sharingItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```